# Databricks cluster policy reference oracle jar

Tags: oracle, jdbc, databricks, cluster-computing, policy

How can I set a Databricks Cluster policy to reference an oracle jar file? I'm creating a policy via JSON (In the UI I'm not allowed to view the Libraries tab while creating the policy). I've done extensive research and have yet to find a suitable answer. My JSON so far looks like this :

"init_scripts.0.dbfs.destination": {
"type": "fixed",
"value": "dbfs:/FileStore/.../ojdbc.jar"
}

The above code doesn't work as the Oracle jar file is not an init_script and it blows up with errors while running the job. Trying to find out if there is a specific policy field name that can replace "init_scripts.0.dbfs.destination". This is the error I'm getting :

*Run result unavailable: run failed with error message
Unexpected failure while waiting for the cluster (XXX) to be ready: Cluster XXX is in unexpected state Terminated: INIT_SCRIPT_FAILURE(CLIENT_ERROR): instance_id:X-XXXX,databricks_error_message:Cluster scoped init script dbfs:/FileStore/.../ojdbc.jar failed: Timed out with exception after 5 attempts (debugStr = 'Reading remote file for init script'), Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Init script at dbfs:/FileStore/.../ojdbc8.jar (4210517 bytes) exceeds the maximum allowed size of 65536 bytes.*

PS : Above error message was edited to remove the exact cluster name, id, and also the complete file path+name of Oracle jar file.

Edited JSON file manually. Was expecting the Oracle Jar file to be successfully loaded, tested this by having a Notebook execute a JDBC query.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you're using is trying to use the `.jar.` file as an init script - this is incorrect.  Libraries in the policy aren't specified in the policy definition, but they should be filled via UI, or use the `libraries` block in the [Cluster Policies Create API](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/clusterpolicies/create).

[image]

P.S. If you don't see the Libraries section in the UI, then maybe it's not yet released for your region.

Comment: I understand this, my question is what is the correct entry for the field name in the JSON policy? So far, not even the Databricks website documentation mentions this. Only reason I tried the InitScript in the policy was to mimic a similar policy. The policy name is definitely not "init_scripts.0.dbfs.destination", it is this part of the code that needs to be changed.

I imagine you could specify this in the Libraries tab, then inspect the generated JSON. Would appreciate if you can share the policy field name. Thanks.

Comment: No. Libraries isn’t a part of the definition field - it’s a separate field inside cluster policy